# submit form using ajax and event.preventDefault() problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, events, event-handling

I have a jquery/ajax form that has `event.preventDefault()`. The problem is that my input field doesn't go empty once I press enter. Usually when you press enter in an input field, it will do the 'action' in the form and the input field empties. But now when I type something, my form doesn't reset to empty when I press enter. I know that event.preventDefault() doesn't do the normal "action" in the form, but I'm trying to not refresh my page and just use ajax so it will load without page refresh.

--------------------jquery-------------------- (below)

```
$('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function(event) {
  $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
    }

  });
  var input = $('input.sel').val();
  dataList = 'list=' + input;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_table_edit.php",
        data: dataList,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
            {
                $('.selector').html(data);
            }
    });
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

---------------ajax_table_edit.php----------- (below)

```
if(isset($_POST['list'])){
$list = $_POST['list'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $id);

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('".$list."')");

echo "success";

}
```

At the same time. I'm trying to echo out success, but that's not working either. Can someone help me seek the solution to this problem?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: On a side note: no need for that regex. You can simply use: `$id = (int) $_POST['id'];`.

Comment: check in the firebug, that the ajax call is made? do you get a response? are there any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to blank the fields yourself with `jQuery: $("#field").val='';`

And its not outputting your message, because you're not grabbing the right variable on success.. you define it as html which may be reserved anyways... try calling it data instead because that is what you're using inside the function anyways.

```
...
success: function(data)
           {
               $('.selector').html(data);
           }
...
```

Also, why do you even have that `$id` code in the php side? looks like it doesn't even get used.  And, just because its ajax doesn't mean you're safe from SQL injection, you need to sanitize that `$_POST['list']` variable.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I forgot to take it out. I know I need to sanitize it. I was thinking of doing all that later on. But do you have any tips on what to use to sanitize it? Thanks again

Comment: @andrewliu There are a lot of posts on preventing sql injection on SO, for starters though use mysql_real_escape_string at minimum, and casting to ints for stuff that should be numeric as mentioned in the other comment is good, and using regex to make sure data is how you expect it is also good.